# How to pre-warm CloudFront edge servers' cache?

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

We have a requirement where we want to pre-warm the cache of all the edge server for a specific CloudFront distribution. For this, we will need to direct a few calls to all the edge servers. Is there any way of identifying all edge servers within a region or globally?

For example:

When going through the information available here: http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/details/

I found that there are multiple edge servers within Asia, lets take Mumbai (India) and Hong Kong for example, I am interested in directing a few HTTP calls to these edge servers. How can I achieve this? If I can get the identity of all these servers, that will be great.

Also, we originally thought of the following approach:
Have a micro instance in all the regions, and access our assets from them.

But there is a problem with this approach. From CloudFront documentation, I have come to understand that there is no hierarchal structure between the edge servers, if any of the edge server does not have the required asset, it directly ask Origin server for that asset. Now, a single region can have multiple edge servers. If within a region, all the edge servers are not having the required assets, then it defeats the purpose of doing this exercise.
So, my question is how to ensure that all the edge servers in a region have the required assets in their cache?

Please note that the content is static in nature. And if covering all edge servers is not possible then even if there is an approach which can cover, lets say, 70% of the edge servers, I would like to try that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here is a post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=105487&tstart=0&messageID=385111#385111) from an Amazon employee from a few years ago regarding pre-warming:

> The issue is, if everyone pre-cached objects to a edge location all of the edge locations would run out of space because they would be flooded with objects that may or may not be being accessed. Right now the edge location only caches objects that are being accessed by users and will dump objects that have no been accessed recently if there is no more room on the server. I am not sure how a pre-cached scenario would work if it were a service.

Unless you know that you're going to be getting a steady flow of traffic over an extended period of time then pre-warming simply may not be effective. CloudFront may very well expire your objects to make room for other customers objects if they're getting more (or more recent) traffic than your own.  Once that happens you've completely lost the advantage of any pre-warming you're able to perform.

Comment: The problem in my case is that the content we are serving does not get accessed very frequently, causing these objects to get evicted all the time. I was hoping to be able to warm the cache on daily basis.
Instead of having a cache in the edge servers, it would have been better for CloudFront to offer storage on these edge servers. Few other CDN are already doing that. If I am not able to get a resolution to this, I might have to move from CloudFront altogether.

Comment: If that's the case then moving out of CloudFront likely does make the most sense for your situation.  If your site is low traffic and you feel the need to pre-warm CDN caches then you're just going to cost yourself a lot of money on AWS.  Each time you run any sort of pre-warming process you'd be incurring charges for those requests, the transfer of the data, etc.

Answer (score 3):

We distribute our app downloads via CloudFront and I need to pre-warm two downloads on the website. We use [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com) for that. They ping the url I provided from random locations across the globe and thus pre-warm the cloudfront cache for us.

Comment: The random locations chosen will be the only one that gets pre-warmed. For the rest of the locations, the cache may not have your app entries. So, unless Pingdom is using some sort of round robin mechanism for hitting at the least all of the popular edge servers, it will not work out.

Comment: Yes, CloudFront have more PoPs than Pingdom and not every one will be covered, but it covers a 10 large cities in US, Sydney and Melbourne in Australia, Singapore and Hong Kong, a couple of cities in Germany, Sweden, France and Greece. This definitely improves average download speed for us.

Comment: That's not the way it works @IvanNikitin. You're not solving your problem at all. The Edge servers have many IPs, and there's complex logic involved in picking which edge server to use even if the request is from "Sydney". Pingdom's request may have triggered only one tiny edge somewhere. That's not prewarming in the way Akamai etc do it.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/chrismay/warmfront looks like a suitable solution. Resolving the CloudFront distribution over multiple DNS servers around the world and sending requests to the resolved IP addresses.

Comment: In principle, yes... though this implementation does not appear to be sufficiently sophisticated.

Comment: The above mentioned script will only be able to direct the calls to a few edge servers in the vicinity. I need to cover all of them.

Plus, I believe it will also execute a get command for all the files I am interested in. Meaning, it will start downloading all those files making this a slow process in case the files are big. Is there a way to warm the cache without having to download the files?

Comment: It's an interesting script @Andreas but the IP list is just Google's DNS, which misses the point of finding all IPs that trigger Cloudfront's IP range: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LocationsOfEdgeServers.html

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you can do this worldwide. Unless you can figure out the IP address of your site around the world from cloudfront.
But if you have a sitemap.xml in your site, you can use wget to get every page in your site cached. It will download the sitemap and then request every page from the sitemap. You can set it up in cron:

```
yoursite=https://yoursite.com
wget --quiet $yoursite/sitemap.xml --output-document - | egrep -o "$yoursite[^<]+" | wget -O/dev/null --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36" --header='Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'  --header='Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br' --header='Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6' --header='Cache-Control:no-cache' --header='Pragma:no-cache' --header='Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1' $yoursite/ -i -
```

Feel free to modify the headers. I noticed unless you specify gzip, it won’t cache gzip. Also if you want to limit the pages -> do it in sitemap.

Get wget for mac by brew or linux by using yum.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to pre-warm the CF cache is to request a specific list of files, such as the list of chunks or fragments of the transcoded video. Those requests may come from different ISPs which connect to different edge caches of CF.

Even if we crate an EC2 instance and RDP or SSH into that instance and wget or curl or otherwise request the video chunks, that will only populate 1-2 edge caches that may or may not be related to the ones you are using and complaining about.

The request cannot specify the edge cache. The request can specify the region of AWS CF, but not the specific edge cache.

Comment: This is, sadly, the correct answer. Amazon would have to offer this as a service, and it'll quickly put CloudFront into the same price range as Akamai etc. In other words, "Enterprise".

Answer (score 1):

If you [enable Origin shield](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/origin-shield.html) in Cloudfront, you can warm it up by hitting any edge. That way, when a different edge makes a request, the origin shield or the regional caches will respond without having to go to the origin server.

[image: Cloudfront with origin shield]